# Exporting the private stylesheet of the current notebook to some other notebook

Tags: programming, front-end

How can the private stylesheet of the current notebook be exported to some other notebook?

Comment: Does it not have value as q&a?

Comment: @Feyre. I think it has value as a self-answered question if the answer actually works reliably. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to test it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
ExportStylesheet::usage =
  "ExportStylesheet[fn]\nExports the private stylesheet of the current notebook to some other one designated by fn. If the notebook designated by fn was open before, one would loose unstored edits. To prevent this, the target notebook is saved automatically before closing it.";
ExportStylesheet[fn_] :=
Module[{nbk}
      ,nbk = NotebookOpen[fn];
       If[nbk == $Failed
         ,Print["ImportStylesheet: Wrong Filename: ", fn]; 
          Throw["Wrong filename!"]  (* ===THROW===> *)
         ];
       SetOptions[nbk
                 ,Options[EvaluationNotebook[]
                 ,StyleDefinitions]
                 ];
       NotebookSave[nbk];  (* safeguard against edit losses *)
       NotebookClose[nbk]; (* closes without asking to store *)
      ];                   (* ExportStylesheet *)
```